# Rails: Converting a text field's linebreaks into <br />

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, line-breaks

I have a text field in my model called 'about', which I'm trying to display on a show page, but none of the line breaks are showing up properly.

I've tried a number of things, but the code I finally landed on is:

```
<%= (h @template.about).gsub("\n", "<br />") %>
```

Unfortunately, Rails seems to be escaping the desired HTML and outputting these line breaks as

```
Thanks for the fish, guys! Not like I wanted it, but... uh... thanks? &lt;br /&gt;
```

How can I properly convert the text field's "\n" linebreaks into actual linebreak HTML? I've already tried simple format as well, to no avail...

I'm using Rails 3, and the first few lines of 'about' are:

> Thanks for the fish, guys! Not like I wanted it, but... uh... thanks? 
>  
>   "I'll be the judge of that," he said! 
> And now, more useless copy so I can isolate that weird bud that Amanda found. 
>   Wait! I meant 'weird bug...'

Comment: which rails version are you using? also provide value of ` `@template.about`

Comment: Edited my above comments to reflect your requests...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

try

```
<%= simple_format @template.about %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

It works for me :-\

```
1.9.3p194 :017 > str = "Thanks for the fish, guys! Not like I wanted it, but... uh... thanks? 
1.9.3p194 :018"> \"I'll be the judge of that,\" he said! 
1.9.3p194 :019"> And now, more useless copy so I can isolate that weird bud that Amanda found. 
1.9.3p194 :020"> Wait! I meant 'weird bug..."
 #=> "Thanks for the fish, guys! Not like I wanted it, but... uh... thanks? \n\"I'll be the judge of that,\" he said! \nAnd now, more useless copy so I can isolate that weird bud that Amanda found. \nWait! I meant 'weird bug..."


1.9.3p194 :021 > simple_format str
 #=> "<p>Thanks for the fish, guys! Not like I wanted it, but... uh... thanks? \n<br />\"I'll be the judge of that,\" he said! \n<br />And now, more useless copy so I can isolate that weird bud that Amanda found. \n<br />Wait! I meant 'weird bug...</p>"
```

or using `gsub`

```
1.9.3p194 :022 > str.gsub("\n", "<br />") 
 #=> "Thanks for the fish, guys! Not like I wanted it, but... uh... thanks? <br />\"I'll be the judge of that,\" he said! <br />And now, more useless copy so I can isolate that weird bud that Amanda found. <br />Wait! I meant 'weird bug..."
```

Comment: "I've already tried simple format as well", I thought, but who knows.

Comment: Yeah, this was one of the first things I tried. Gave it another shot, just for good measure, but it didn't do the trick.

Comment: Strangely enough, according to my server logs, this works. I did a put of the updated text, and it came out: 
<p>Thanks for the fish, guys! Not like I wanted it, but... uh... thanks? 
<br />"I'll be the judge of that," he said! And now, more useless copy so I can isolate that weird bud that Amanda found. 
<br />Wait! I meant 'weird bug...'</p>
However, it's still one giant wall of text on my show page...

Comment: is its display tags like `<p>` in text or is rendered as html

Comment: It just doesn't display the tags, neither as text nor as HTML

Comment: this means the text is being rendered properly but something else is messing it up... !!

Comment: Okay, that's a start. Any ideas what could be messing it up? Or how I start looking for the problem?

Comment: try playing in firebug with css properties :)

Comment: Turns out it was a rogue bit of JavaScript messing things up... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= (h @template.about).gsub("\n", "<br />").html_safe %>
```

The `h` helper **escapes** the text so you aren't left open to XSS attacks. Once that text is escaped, you can `gsub` and declare the new string to be `html_safe`.

`html_safe` is **not escaping**, it's the declaration that the string shouldn't be escaped. But you do want to escape the original string unless you are sure it does not contain user input.